# How can i make this for random 6 digit number

Tags: python, python-requests

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import itertools
import time

keyboard = Controller()

for i in reversed(range(5)):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

for combination in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6):
    laina = (''.join(map(str, combination)))

    keyboard.type(laina)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press('a')
    keyboard.release('a')
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Do I understand you want to type a 6 digit number? Such as typing "123456"?

Comment: yes thats about right

Comment: `keyboard.type(str(random.randrange(100000,999999)))` should type a random 6 digit number provided you `import random`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random 6-digit integer with `random.randint(0, 999999).`

If you need your value `x` padded with left zeros to make a six-digit string, then use f"{x:06d}".